# The meaning of $\ast$ in $\{0,1\}^\ast$ and of $\lambda$ such that $\forall x\in\{0,1\}^\ast$ we have $\lambda x=x$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation, induction, proof-explanation

I have the following homework problem.

> (a)  Prove by structural induction that for all $x ∈\{ 0 , 1 \} ^∗$ , $λx = 
>  x$.
>
> (b)  Consider  the  function reverse : $\{ 0 , 1 \}^∗ → \{ 0 , 1 \} ^∗$ which
>   reverses a  binary  string,  e.g, reverse $(01001)  =  10010$.   Give 
>   an  inductive definition for reverse . (Assume that we defined { 0 , 1
>   } $^∗$ and concatenation of binary strings as we did in lecture.)
>
> (c)  Using your inductive definition, prove that for all $x,y ∈ \{ 0 , 1
>  \} ^∗$ , reverse ($xy$) = reverse ($y$) reverse ($x$). (You  may  assume 
>   that  concatenation  is  associative,  i.e.,  for  all $x,y,z ∈ \{ 0 , 1 \} ^∗$ , $x ( yz ) = ( xy ) z$ .

I understand how to do (c), but do not understand what "$\{ 0 , 1 \} ^∗$" is (specifically I don't understand what the asterisk denotes, otherwise I would assume it is just the set containing 1 and 0) and what "$λ$" is. Most of my questions about (a) and (b) stem from these misunderstandings.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Also, please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asterisk is the [Kleene star](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) and $\lambda$ is the empty word. The latter is more commonly denoted by $\varepsilon$. Some authors use $1$ as well (especially when considering, say, $X^*$ as a monoid for some set $X$, under concatenation).

Comment: My pleasure. Thank you for updating your answer.